# How to check for EOF without readLine()?

Tags: java

I have a method that read the next line in a txt file and does something. I have another method that needs to check for EOF as well. The two methods are called receptively within a loop.

method 1:

```java
trace = br.readLine();
   if (trace==null)
       break; // end of file
```

method 2: 
I need to check for EOF without using the same technique. Otherwise, it would increment the ptr used for readLine...

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517638/can-i-peek-on-a-bufferedreader and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2517713/1227804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);
```

and read

```
 while (sc.hasNext ())
```

Scanner has a

```
  sc.readLine ();
```

method.

Comment: This generic answer doesn't begin to solve OP's specific request to check for EOF at two places in the code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Wrong! `Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.` You can invoke the method at different points.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to accomplish this?

The BufferedReader API doesn't allow you to do this (*).  If you really need to do this, you'll need to implement a custom Reader class to do this.  I'd start with `PushbackReader`, add a `readLine()` method and then implement an eof test method by reading one char and pushing it back.

<sub>* From reading the answers to [Can I peek on a BufferedReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517638/can-i-peek-on-a-bufferedreader), it appears that the `ready()` method might work as an EOF test.  However, this is an artifact of the current implementations of `ready()` in the standard code-base, and is arguably wrong (a bug) according to the javadoc specification of the method.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format to check as well to avoid EOF exception. Since the buffer size is determined early it will not cause any error to occur.

```
File myFile = new File("path");
String completeText = "";
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(myFile.getAbsoluteFile()).getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)fc.size());
fc.read(buffer);
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();  
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();  
CharBuffer charBuffer = decoder.decode(buffer);    
completeText = charBuffer.toString();
buffer.clear();
fc.close();
```